# What does the Object<type> syntax mean in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

In the following code example, from the [flutter docs](https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/#step-3-add-a-stateful-widget):

```
class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => RandomWordsState();
}

class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wordPair = WordPair.random();
    return Text(wordPair.asPascalCase);
  }
}
```

What exactly does the `State<RandomWords>` syntax mean?

I understand that you can specify the type for the objects contained in a collection, like lists, using this syntax - `List <String>`

But I cannot understand the motive behind `State<RandomWords>`.

Moreover, how can you reference `RandomWordsState` in `RandomWords` declaration and also reference `RandomWords` in `RandomWordsState` declaration? Shouldn't that cause a circular reference error or something?

I come from dynamically typed languages like python, and this looks a little odd to me, can someone please point me to the right place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<RandomWords>` is a generic type parameter passed to the `State` class.

The `State` class looks like

```
abstract class State<T extends StatefulWidget> extends Diagnosticable {
```

and `RandomWords` will be passed to the `T` type parameter which has a constraint that `T` needs to be a subclass of `StatefulWidget`.

`State` also has a field and getter where the type parameter is used

```
  T get widget => _widget;
  T _widget;
```

This results in a property of the type of the widget
which provides proper autocompletion and type checks in its subclass `RandomWordsState`

Assume you have

```
class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  RandomWords({this.fixed});

  final WordPair fixed;

  @override
  createState() => RandomWordsState();
}

class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // vvvv here we can access `fixed` in a strongly typed manner
    final wordPair = widget.fixed ?? WordPair.random();
    return Text(wordPair.asPascalCase);
  }
}
```

See also https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#generics

Comment: So in plain english, one would say that "RandomWordsState is the state object for the RandomWords widget", correct?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't say much about the generics syntax ;-) I got the impression your question was about generics. If it was about `RandomWords` vs `RandomWordsState` then yes, Flutter has short-lived widgets and longer lived widget state and for stateful widgets you have a widget and a related state - the 2 classes in your question are such a pair.

Comment: It was sort of both I guess :), thanks for the explanation.